# Insert NULL in DB when datepicker is empty with Ajax Laravel

Tags: javascript, ajax, database, laravel, datepicker

I use laravel and in my view I have an input datepicker like this :

```
{!! Form::text('DESMES_Date_Analyses',null ,['class' => 'form-control datepicker']) !!}
```

With this code :

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        todayHighlight: true,
        language : 'fr'
    });
```

And I get the value with something like this :

```
var date_analyses = $(this).find("input[name=DESMES_Date_Analyses]").val();
```

After that I insert in Database the value with Ajax request :

```
$.ajax({
            url: './register',
             headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token},
            data: {
                 DESMES_Date_Analyses : date_analyses
            },
            type: 'POST',
            datatype: 'JSON'
)};
```

And in my controller I do :

```
 public function register(Request $request) {
    if($request->ajax()) {
        Mesures::create($request->all());
    }
}
```

But if the value is empty, in my database I have 1900-01-01 and I just want NULL instead of this default date.
How can I do this?

I tried to set date_analyses to null in javascript before sending it to my controller but it doesn't work... Thank you!

Comment: is 'date_analyses' really empty?

Comment: Yes and in case date_analyses is not empty, I tried setting it to null directly in javascript before sending it to my controller but I have the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution : In my controller, just before the request to insert I put :

```
if($request->DESMES_Date_Analyses==""){$request->offsetSet('DESMES_Date_Analyses', NULL);}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is your database table, which inserts 1900-01-01 while there is a null value passed for date_analyses. So check that once.

Comment: When I try in SQL in my database I can to insert NULL for this column

Comment: What is the field type of that column in table? Does it have any default value assigned?

Comment: Also in controller, make that date_analyays is empty. Check like this dd($this->date_analysys)

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, you have to set `nullable()` on the table field you want to make nullable:

```
$table->date('DESMES_Date_Analyses')->nullable();
```

Some things to consider is that,

- The field cannot be unique

After then (maybe), one important thing to do is to do some manual check on your `DESMES_Date_Analyses` param before saving it (and say you have other fields like name as well.).

```
.......
$data = [];
$data['name'] == $request->get('name');
if($date_analyses = $request->get('DESMES_Date_Analyses')) //i.e not null/empty
{
    $data['DESMES_Date_Analyses'] = date_analyses;        
}
Mesures::create($data); //so if date_analyses is not in the field it is saved as NULL
```

This means that if `DESMES_Date_Analyses` is not present then the query would exclude `DESMES_Date_Analyses` and set the field to NULL. Meaning that the query might look like this:

```
insert into the_table ('name') values ('some name'); //excluding the field `DESMES_Date_Analyses`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `NULL` instate of empty value.

> Note : column must be nullable.

```
public function register(Request $request) {

    $data = $request->input();

    if($data['DESMES_Date_Analyses'] == ''){
        $data['DESMES_Date_Analyses'] = NULL;
    }

    if($request->ajax()) {
        Mesures::create($data);
    }
}
```